# how to move flexslider to last slide

Tags: jquery, arrays, flexslider

I have a flexslider object that's working perfectly.
However I have an anchor on the page that needs to move the carousel to the last slide.
Also the slide number can vary, so targeting a specific index value won't satisfy the requirements.

I have no trouble moving to specific indexes, as such (moves to first index position):

```
$('.flexslider').data("flexslider").flexAnimate(0);
```

I imagine there's some type of keyword, or perhaps an equation but I haven't found a reliable resource.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you were close to the answer. 
You can get the index of any concerned element in a collection/selector by `.index()` function.

Now, let's say you have ul of class `.slides` containing several `li`.

For getting the index of last li:

```
var index = $('.slides li').index($('.slides li:last'));
```

now since you've got the index of the desired slide, you can pass this index into `flexslider` to activate or show that slide:

```
$('.flexslider').data("flexslider").flexAnimate(index);
```

You can see that by default the slider begins from the last slide. Hope this helps

Further, you can use this into a `click handler`

**Update:** There was an issue with slide which doesn't allow manual sliding unless the next or prev links are clicked for the slider.
The possible fix which I found is:

```
var lastSlide = $('.slides li').index($('.slides li:last'));
$("a.specs").click(function () {    
    flex.flexslider('next'); // This is the trick. 
    flex.flexslider(lastSlide)
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/n9JUc/21/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! This is definitely the direction I was attempting to go. I have this in place and in a click handler, however, it doesn't want to animate. I'm getting a response in the console.log that shows me which index is selected but no movement in the slider... I'm using an anchor that is outside the flex controls, perhaps there's a scope issue?

Comment: Share that code here. I don't think it will be a scope issue

Comment: var lastSlide = $('.slides li').index($('.slides li:last'));

  $("a.specs").click(function(){
    console.log(lastSlide);
    $('.flexslider').data("flexslider").flexAnimate(lastSlide);
  });

Comment: It's working for me here : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/CPpBD/55/ . Defined your lastSlide globally and then try. It should work

Comment: That's how it's currently set up in my DOM ready event... maybe I'm getting a conflict from somewhere else?! Thank you so much for the assistance, I thought I was losing my mind when I couldn't get this to work. I'll have to dig deeper to find out why I'm having no luck.

Comment: Yeah maybe. Log those values in console. Check for the value of lastSlide. Maybe you are having one or two class different than in the fiddle.Best of luck

Comment: ...apparently it will trigger the animation but only after I've clicked to a slide. I'm guessing it's not recognizing the click event until the slider has been manipulated somehow... (maybe not the best explanation, just spit-ballin' here).

Comment: well,it would be better if you can create a fiddle for your code then only I can help you more on this. As you can see, the fiddle works fine. There has to be something in your code.

Comment: in the process of creating the fiddle I've isolated the issue...  http://jsfiddle.net/travhall/n9JUc/12/  ... apparently using Modernizr calls to manipulate flexslider settings creates some type of conflict. Feeling better about my competency but even more lost on how to fix. Any thoughts?

Comment: apparently I was incorrect with my last post, it's still not sliding to the last position until the slider's own nav gets clicked.

Comment: sorry, left a stupid error in the last fiddle link. here it is but still broken http://jsfiddle.net/travhall/n9JUc/18/

Comment: Check the updated answer. I added some update in the end of the answer. Hope this helps you.'

Comment: KK, thank you soooooo much, works like a charm!!! (as soon as my rep is up, I'm gonna upvote this response) ... you are a true javascript ninja!

Answer (score 2):

If you bypass the .flexslider helper function, then you can override the internal checker.

```
$('.flexslider').data("flexslider").flexAnimate(index, true, true);
```

The third parameter is the override parameter. It basically forces flexslider to animate to that slide even it doesn't pass the internal check of the canAdvance check.

This is necessary if you want to fade the animation instead of sliding. K K's work around doesn't work with the fade animation.